# Choose a specific java version for neo4j or cocoon

Tags: java, neo4j, freebsd, apache-cocoon

I'm currently running cocoon on my FreeBSD server (9.2) I'm using this version of java :

`java -version
openjdk version "1.6.0_32"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_32-b28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)`

But I would like also to use Neo4j which needs Java 7.
I did a `pkg opendjk7` but I don't know how to tell Neo4j to use this version of Java (in my PATH I have Java 6).

What should I do ?

Thanks a lot
Sincerely
A.H

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have both JDK installed at the same time, if JDK 6 is the default, don't change anything to the startup script of cocoon, but in the script startup script of Neo4j, just set

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path_to_JDK7
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks I was looking for a solution for a long time. It's know working. Have a nice day. Sincerely

Comment: How do you know which JRE version is installed? I used `java -version`, but the numbers were very far from 7: `java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK Zero VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)`. According to neo4j, it requires JRE 7 now. I am confused, should I update, or is the problem with the environment variables?

Comment: where is that script? Is that on bin?